# changin nan values in imagesc to 0 after printing

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, vector, physics

The way I used imagesc is that I added each layer on top of the other because they have different boundries.
the problem is that because I used such ways beyond the boundry at the start there is NaN values. 
My question is how can I change the NaN values to 0 after I already printed the function?
 The code is the following:

```
N = 2^9;
z = ones(N-1,1);
c = 1;
ranNum = diag(rand([N 1])-ones(N,1)/2);
Nsig = 10^2;
sigma = ones(Nsig,1).';
E = ones(Nsig,N);
IPR = ones(Nsig,N);
sigjump = 0.01;


for j = 1:Nsig
    sigma(j) = sigjump + sigjump*(j-1);
    H1 = c*(diag(z,1)+ diag(z,-1) + diag(1,N-1)+ diag(1,-N+1));
    V1 = sigma(j) * ranNum ;
    H = H1 + V1;
    [psi,~] = eig(H);
    E(j,:) = eig(H);
    P1 = abs(psi).^2;
    IPR(j,:) = sum(P1.^2);
    
    imagesc(E(j,:),sigma(j)+sigjump*Nsig/2 ,IPR(j,:));
    colormap('turbo')
    colorbar
    xlabel('E')
    ylabel('sigma')
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h, 'IPR')
    hold on
   
end
```

This is the result (the white at the top left), also, you cant see the entire spectrum.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Are you asking how to replace NaN values in your data set with 0?

Comment: yes, I need to change the NaN values to 0 after already using the function @GrapefruitIsAwesome

Answer (score 0):

I don't have matlab, but i guess that's the same with Octave (and Scilab):

```
>> a = rand(2,4)
a =
   0.257914   0.775035   0.608284   0.057678
   0.162044   0.491000   0.285110   0.766687

>> a(a<0.3) = NaN
a =
      NaN   0.7750   0.6083      NaN
      NaN   0.4910      NaN   0.7667

>> a(isnan(a)) = 0
a =
        0   0.7750   0.6083        0
        0   0.4910        0   0.7667
```